# Set Pandas Hierarchical Multi-Index from a dataframe created using a nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a nested dictionary with 3 levels,

```
example_d = {'attribute_001': {'colour': {'blue': 5, 'green': 5, 'red': 5},
                   'country': {'France': 3, 'Germany': 3, 'India': 3, 'UK': 3, 'USA': 3}},
  'attribute_002': {'colour': {'blue': 5, 'green': 5, 'red': 5},
                   'country': {'France': 3, 'Germany': 3, 'India': 3, 'UK': 3, 'USA': 3}},
  'attribute_003': {'colour': {'blue': 5, 'green': 5, 'red': 5},
                   'country': {'France': 3, 'Germany': 3, 'India': 3, 'UK': 3, 'USA': 3}},
  'attribute_004': {'colour': {'blue': 5, 'green': 5, 'red': 5},
                   'country': {'France': 3, 'Germany': 3, 'India': 3, 'UK': 3, 'USA': 3}},
  'attribute_005': {'colour': {'blue': 5, 'green': 5, 'red': 5}, 
                   'country': {'France': 3, 'Germany': 3, 'India': 3, 'UK': 3, 'USA': 3}}}
```

and I want to move this into a pandas dataframe such that the row-index is sourced at the first level of my dictionary, and use the remaining levels as hierarchical column indices.

I can get close by using the following, adapting an answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575090/construct-pandas-dataframe-from-items-in-nested-dictionary):

```
pd.concat({key:pd.DataFrame.from_dict(example_d[key],orient='columns')
              for key in example_d.keys()}).unstack(1)
```

which gives me:

[image]

But I need the lowest level of the multi-level column indices to respect their parents.

i.e. under the `colour` heading, I want only colour-columns to appear, and under the `country` heading, I want to see only country-columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First change [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39807565), pass to `Series` constructor and reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
reform = {(level1_key, level2_key, level3_key): values
             for level1_key, level2_dict in example_d.items()
             for level2_key, level3_dict in level2_dict.items()
             for level3_key, values in level3_dict.items()}

df = pd.Series(reform).unstack(level=[1,2])
print (df)
              colour           country                     
                blue green red  France Germany India UK USA
attribute_001      5     5   5       3       3     3  3   3
attribute_002      5     5   5       3       3     3  3   3
attribute_003      5     5   5       3       3     3  3   3
attribute_004      5     5   5       3       3     3  3   3
attribute_005      5     5   5       3       3     3  3   3
```

Comment: Both answers work, but this one has the edge for me as it sets out a clear approach for dealing with not only this particular example, but with only some simple adjustment, could also be more generally applied to other nested dictionaries of different depth - by constructing tuple-keyed indices - which can then be managed using `stack` and `unstack`.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC using `concat`

```
df= pd.DataFrame(example_d).T
pd.concat([df[x].apply(pd.Series) for x in list(df)],1,keys=list(df))
Out[540]: 
              colour           country                     
                blue green red  France Germany India UK USA
attribute_001      5     5   5       3       3     3  3   3
attribute_002      5     5   5       3       3     3  3   3
attribute_003      5     5   5       3       3     3  3   3
attribute_004      5     5   5       3       3     3  3   3
attribute_005      5     5   5       3       3     3  3   3
```

Comment: Both these answers are neat in their own way - this one most closely follows the stacked construction I had started with.