# Pandas Dataframe from nested dictionary of pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, nested

I have a dictionary with keys of 2 levels, and values at the second level being dataframes:

```
my_dict = {
           'elem1':{'day1': pd.DataFrame(columns=['Col1', 'Col2']),
                    'day2': pd.DataFrame(columns=['Col1', 'Col2'])
                   },
           'elem2':{'day1': pd.DataFrame(columns=['Col1', 'Col2']),
                    'day2': pd.DataFrame(columns=['Col1', 'Col2'])
                    'day3': pd.DataFrame(columns=['Col1', 'Col2'])
                   }
          }
```

How do I convert this to a multi-index pandas dataframe of the form:

```
                 Col1    Col2
elem1    day1    ...      ...
         day2    ...      ...
elem2    day1    ...      ...
         day2    ...      ...
```

I have looked through these answers but am unable to stitch together a solution:

- [Nested dictionary to multiindex dataframe where dictionary keys are column labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988131/nested-dictionary-to-multiindex-dataframe-where-dictionary-keys-are-column-label)
- [Nested Dictionary to MultiIndex pandas DataFrame (3 level)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30384581/nested-dictionary-to-multiindex-pandas-dataframe-3-level)
- [Construct pandas DataFrame from items in nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575090/construct-pandas-dataframe-from-items-in-nested-dictionary)
- [Convert list of dictionaries to a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638006/convert-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-pandas-dataframe/53831756#53831756)
- [Nested dictionary to multiindex dataframe where dictionary keys are column labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988131/nested-dictionary-to-multiindex-dataframe-where-dictionary-keys-are-column-label)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Idea is create tuples by both keys and pass to [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), third level of `MultiIndex` is created from index values of original `DataFrame`s, if necessary you can remove it:

```
my_dict = {
           'elem1':{'day1': pd.DataFrame(1, columns=['Col1', 'Col2'], index=[1,2]),
                    'day2': pd.DataFrame(2, columns=['Col1', 'Col2'], index=[1,2])
                   },
           'elem2':{'day1': pd.DataFrame(3, columns=['Col1', 'Col2'], index=[1,2]),
                    'day2': pd.DataFrame(4, columns=['Col1', 'Col2'], index=[1,2]),
                    'day3': pd.DataFrame(5, columns=['Col1', 'Col2'], index=[1,2])
                   }
          }
```

---

```
d = {(k1, k2): v2 for k1, v1 in my_dict.items() for k2, v2 in v1.items()}
print (d)
{('elem1', 'day1'):    Col1  Col2
1     1     1
2     1     1, ('elem1', 'day2'):    Col1  Col2
1     2     2
2     2     2, ('elem2', 'day1'):    Col1  Col2
1     3     3
2     3     3, ('elem2', 'day2'):    Col1  Col2
1     4     4
2     4     4, ('elem2', 'day3'):    Col1  Col2
1     5     5
2     5     5}

df = pd.concat(d, sort=False)
print (df)
              Col1  Col2
elem1 day1 1     1     1
           2     1     1
      day2 1     2     2
           2     2     2
elem2 day1 1     3     3
           2     3     3
      day2 1     4     4
           2     4     4
      day3 1     5     5
           2     5     5
```

---

```
df = pd.concat(d, sort=False).reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
print (df)
            Col1  Col2
elem1 day1     1     1
      day1     1     1
      day2     2     2
      day2     2     2
elem2 day1     3     3
      day1     3     3
      day2     4     4
      day2     4     4
      day3     5     5
      day3     5     5
```

Comment: Great answer, I just had to modify the line:
`df = pd.concat(d, sort=False)`
since I wanted a particular column upfront

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
my_dict = {
           'elem1':{'day1': pd.DataFrame(columns=['Col1', 'Col2']),
                    'day2': pd.DataFrame(columns=['Col1', 'Col2'])
                   },
           'elem2':{'day1': pd.DataFrame(columns=['Col1', 'Col2']),
                    'day2': pd.DataFrame(columns=['Col1', 'Col2'])
                    'day3': pd.DataFrame(columns=['Col1', 'Col2'])
                   }
          }
nd = {}
for x in my_dict:
  nd.update(my_dict[x])
df = pd.DataFrame(nd,index=my_dict.keys())
```