# Convert nested dictionary to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary as below:

```
stud_data_dict = { 's1' : {'Course 1' : {'Course Name':'Maths', 
                                         'Marks':95,
                                         'Grade': 'A+'},
                           'Course 2' : {'Course Name':'Science', 
                                         'Marks': 75,
                                         'Grade': 'B-'}},
                   's2' : {'Course 1' : {'Course Name':'English', 
                                         'Marks': 82,
                                         'Grade': 'B'},
                           'Course 2' : {'Course Name':'Maths', 
                                         'Marks': 90,
                                         'Grade': 'A'}}}
```

I need to convert it into a dataframe like below

```
  Student   Course 1                   Course 2
            Course Name  Marks  Grade  Course Name  Marks  Grade
    s1      Maths        95     A+     Science      75     B-
    s2      English      82     B      Maths        90     A
```

I have tired the following code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61089196/2246380)

```
stud_df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(stud_data_dict, orient="index").stack().to_frame()
final_df = pandas.DataFrame(stud_df[0].values.tolist(), index=stud_df.index)
```

I am getting the dataframe like below

```
              Course Name  Marks  Grade             
s1  Course 1  Maths        95     A+
    Course 2  Science      75     B-
s2  Course 1  English      82     B
    Course 2  Maths        90     A
```

This is the closest I got to the desired output. What changes do I need to make to the code to get the desired dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `dictionary` first and then pass to `Series` with reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
#reformat nested dict
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/39807565/2901002
d  = {(level1_key, level2_key, level3_key): values
       for level1_key, level2_dict in stud_data_dict.items()
       for level2_key, level3_dict in level2_dict.items()
       for level3_key, values      in level3_dict.items()}

stud_df = pd.Series(d).unstack([1,2])
print (stud_df)
    Course 1                Course 2            
   Course Name Marks Grade Course Name Marks Grade
s1       Maths    95    A+     Science    75    B-
s2     English    82     B       Maths    90     A
```

Another idea is created dictionary of tuples in keys with [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)

for k, v in stud_data_dict.items():
    for k1, v1 in v.items():
        for k2, v2 in v1.items():
            d[(k1, k2)].update({k: v2})

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
      Course 1                Course 2            
   Course Name Marks Grade Course Name Marks Grade
s1       Maths    95    A+     Science    75    B-
s2     English    82     B       Maths    90     A
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create data frames from the inner dictionaries, concatenate into a single frame, reshape and cleanup:

```py
out = {key: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(value, orient='index') 
       for key, value in stud_data_dict.items()}

(pd
.concat(out)
.unstack()
.swaplevel(axis = 1)
.sort_index(axis = 1)
.rename_axis('Student')
.reset_index()
)
  Student    Course 1                Course 2
          Course Name Grade Marks Course Name Grade Marks
0      s1       Maths    A+    95     Science    B-    75
1      s2     English     B    82       Maths     A    90
```

You should get more performance if you can do all the initial wrangling in vanilla python or numpy, before creating the final dataframe:

```py
out = []; outer = []; bottom = []; index = [];

for key, value in stud_data_dict.items():
     out = []
     for k, v in value.items():
         out.extend(v.values())
     outer.append(out)
     index.append(key)
     bottom.extend(v.keys())

top = np.repeat([*value.keys()], len(v))

pd.DataFrame(outer, 
             columns = [top, bottom], 
             index = index)

      Course 1                Course 2            
   Course Name Marks Grade Course Name Marks Grade
s1       Maths    95    A+     Science    75    B-
s2     English    82     B       Maths    90     A
```

Comment: hmm, performance is issue for `concat + DataFrames in list comprehension`.

Comment: True, better performance is doing everything outside of python before creating the DataFrame