# multiindex dataframe from nested dictionary of sets

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a nested dictionary of sets of dates, d

```
d= {"A": {'a': {datetime1, datetime2}, 'b': {datetime3}, 'c':{datetime4},
    "B": {'a': datetime5, datetime1, datetime3}}
```

I want a pandas DataFrame df

```
          dates   
A    a    datetime1
          datetime2
     b    datetime3
          ...
```

This might be a duplicate question of
[Nested dictionary to multiindex dataframe where dictionary keys are column labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988131/nested-dictionary-to-multiindex-dataframe-where-dictionary-keys-are-column-label)

However, I couldn't get the advise given in that question to work here, so I dare to repost the question. (However, I have previously successfully used methods in that question on other nested dictionaries). So, doing something like

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({(i, j): d[i][j]
                                     for i in d.keys()
                                     for j in d[i].keys()},
                                     orient='index')
```

creates a mess of thousands of integers as columns (one for each date maybe?), and tuple (i,j) as a single index (instead of two levels of indexes, i and j). Is the problem simply because here I have only one column in the dataframe? Can't I have a multiindexed series? Or am I missing something very obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should separate the dict into the indices and their data, then make a `pd.MultiIndex` and a `pd.Series`.  I'm working off the example given [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html), but modified slightly for your dictionary.

```
index, series = zip(*[((i, j), d[i][j]) for i in d for j in d[i]])

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index, names=['Captial', 'lowercase'])
series = pd.Series(series, index=index)
```

Comment: The first line returns "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)". Can you suggest some slight modification?

Comment: You, dear sir, are a lifesaver :)