# How to merge Pandas dataframes without duplicating columns

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have data of the form:

```
frame1 = pd.DataFrame({'supplier1_match0': ['x'], 'id': [1]})
frame2 = pd.DataFrame({'supplier1_match0': ['2x'], 'id': [2]})
```

and wish to left join multiple frames to a frame like this:

```
base_frame = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3]})
```

I merge on the id and get:

```
merged = base_frame.merge(frame1, how='left', left_on='id', right_on='id')
merged = merged.merge(frame2, how='left', left_on='id', right_on='id')

   id supplier1_match0_x supplier1_match0_y
0   1                  x                NaN
1   2                NaN                 2x
2   3                NaN                NaN
```

The column is duplicated and a 'y' is appended. Here is what I need:

```
id, supplier1_match0, ...
1,  x
2,  2x
3, NaN
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this? There is a similar question ([Nested dictionary to multiindex dataframe where dictionary keys are column labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988131/nested-dictionary-to-multiindex-dataframe-where-dictionary-keys-are-column-label)) but the data has a different shape. Note that I have multiple suppliers and that they have varying numbers of matches, so I can't assume the data will have a "rectangular" shape. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the indices the same length and in order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't really want to just `merge` everything. You need to `concat` your first set of frames, then merge.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

base_frame.merge(pd.concat([frame1, frame2]), how='left')

#   id supplier1_match0
#0   1                x
#1   2               2x
#2   3              NaN
```

---

Alternatively, you could define `base_frame` so that it has all of the relevant columns of the other frames and set `id` to be the index and use `.update`. This ensures `base_frame` remains the same size, while the above does not. Though data would be over-written if there are multiple non-null values for a given cell.

```
base_frame = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3]}).assign(supplier1_match0 = np.NaN).set_index('id')

for df in [frame1, frame2]:
    base_frame.update(df.set_index('id'))

print(base_frame)

   supplier1_match0
id                 
1                 x
2                2x
3               NaN
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I did not know about DataFrame.update

Answer (score -1):

```
newdf_merge= pd.merge(pd.DataFrame(df1), pd.DataFrame(df2), left_on=['common column name from df1'],right_on=['common column name from df2'],how='left')
```

It worked for me , hence wanted to share it here