# Avoid duplicate columns while merging with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have dozens of dataframes I would like to merge with a "reference" dataframe. I want to merge the columns when they exist in both dataframes, or conversely, create a new one when they don't already exist. I have the feeling that this is closely related to this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57408583/pandas-merge-without-duplicating-columns) but I cannot figure out out to make it work in my case. 
Also, note that the key used for merging never contains duplicates.

```
# Reference dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'date_time':['2018-06-01 00:00:00','2018-06-01 00:30:00','2018-06-01 01:00:00','2018-06-01 01:30:00']})

# Dataframes to merge to reference dataframe
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date_time':['2018-06-01 00:30:00','2018-06-01 01:00:00'],
                'potato':[13,21]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date_time':['2018-06-01 01:30:00','2018-06-01 02:00:00','2018-06-01 02:30:00'],
                'carrot':[14,8,32]})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'date_time':['2018-06-01 01:30:00','2018-06-01 02:00:00'],
                'potato':[27,31]})


df = df.merge(df1, how='left', on='date_time')
df = df.merge(df2, how='left', on='date_time')
df = df.merge(df3, how='left', on='date_time')
```

The result is :

```
              date_time  potato_x  carrot  potato_y
0  2018-06-01 00:00:00       NaN     NaN       NaN
1  2018-06-01 00:30:00      13.0     NaN       NaN
2  2018-06-01 01:00:00      21.0     NaN       NaN
3  2018-06-01 01:30:00       NaN    14.0      27.0
```

While I would like :

```
              date_time  potato  carrot 
0  2018-06-01 00:00:00       NaN     NaN  
1  2018-06-01 00:30:00      13.0     NaN   
2  2018-06-01 01:00:00      21.0     NaN 
3  2018-06-01 01:30:00      27.0    14.0
```

**Edit** (following @sammywemmy's answer): 
I have no idea what will be the dataframe columns name before importing them (in a loop). Usually, the dataframes that are merged with my reference dataframe contain about 100 columns, from which 90%-95% are common with the other dataframes.

Comment: so the final dataframe will have about 100 columns?

Comment: Every new dataframe to be merge contains about 100 columns. Among these 100 columns, there might be 10 columns that have a name that is not present in the previous dataframes. So, assuming that I want to merge 15 dataframes, I will have at the end 100 columns + 15*10 = 250 columns

Comment: it seems the other columns are food names (potato, carrot,...) and the common key is date_time. 100 columns is a lot and i dont see how you can keep track of that. I suggest you write code that melts every dataframe, using date_time as your index_var, then perform the merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would `pd.concat` similar structured dataframes then `merge` the others like this:

```
df.merge(pd.concat([df1, df3]), on='date_time', how='left')\
  .merge(df2, on='date_time', how='left')
```

Output:

```
             date_time  potato  carrot
0  2018-06-01 00:00:00     NaN     NaN
1  2018-06-01 00:30:00    13.0     NaN
2  2018-06-01 01:00:00    21.0     NaN
3  2018-06-01 01:30:00    27.0    14.0
```

---

Per comments below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date_time':['2018-06-01 00:00:00','2018-06-01 00:30:00','2018-06-01 01:00:00','2018-06-01 01:30:00']})

# Dataframes to merge to reference dataframe
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date_time':['2018-06-01 00:30:00','2018-06-01 01:00:00'],
                'potato':[13,21]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date_time':['2018-06-01 01:30:00','2018-06-01 02:00:00','2018-06-01 02:30:00'],
                'carrot':[14,8,32]})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'date_time':['2018-06-01 01:30:00', '2018-06-01 02:00:00'],'potato':[27,31], 'zucchini':[11,1]})

df.merge(pd.concat([df1, df3]), on='date_time', how='left').merge(df2, on='date_time', how='left')
```

Output:

```
             date_time  potato  zucchini  carrot
0  2018-06-01 00:00:00     NaN       NaN     NaN
1  2018-06-01 00:30:00    13.0       NaN     NaN
2  2018-06-01 01:00:00    21.0       NaN     NaN
3  2018-06-01 01:30:00    27.0      11.0    14.0
```

Comment: I think your solution works only if the merged/concatenated dataframe is either fully similar or diffirent from df. For example, I wouldn't know how to deal with a dataframe such as : `df3 = pd.DataFrame({'date_time':['2018-06-01 01:30:00', '2018-06-01 02:00:00'],'potato':[27,31], 'zucchini':[11,1]})`

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from your code,
 use the [filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) method to pull out potato related columns,
 sum them along the columns axis, 
 and remove columns that contain potato_...

```
df['potato'] = df.filter(like='potato').fillna(0).sum(axis=1)

exclude_columns = df.columns.str.contains('potato_[a-z]')
df = df.loc[:,~exclude_columns]

    date_time         carrot    potato
0   2018-06-01 00:00:00 NaN     0.0
1   2018-06-01 00:30:00 NaN     13.0
2   2018-06-01 01:00:00 NaN     21.0
3   2018-06-01 01:30:00 14.0    27.0
```

Comment: I have no idea what will be the columns name before importing them. To be more precise, every new dataframe contains about 100 columns, from which 90%-95% are common with the other dataframes. I edited my question to add these information.