# Construct MultiIndex pandas DataFrame nested Python dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to construct a MultiIndex DataFrame from a deeply-nested dictionary of the form

```
md = {'50': {'100': {'col1': ('0.100',
                              '0.200',
                              '0.300',
                              '0.400'),
                     'col2': ('6.263E-03',
                              '6.746E-03',
                              '7.266E-03',
                              '7.825E-03')},
             '101': {'col1': ('0.100',
                              '0.200',
                              '0.300',
                              '0.400'),
                     'col2': ('6.510E-03',
                              '7.011E-03',
                              '7.553E-03',
                              '8.134E-03')}
             '102': ...
            }
      '51': ...
     }
```

I've tried

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({(i,j): md[i][j][v] for i in md.keys() for j in md[i].keys() for v in md[i][j]}, orient='index')
```

following [Construct pandas DataFrame from items in nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575090/construct-pandas-dataframe-from-items-in-nested-dictionary), but I get a DataFrame with 1 row and many columns.

Bonus:
I'd also like to label the MultiIndex keys and the columns 'col1' and 'col2', as well as convert the strings to `int` and `float`, respectively.

How can I reconstruct my original dictionary from the dataframe?
I tried `df.to_dict('list')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24988227/9404057. This method unpacks the keys and values of the dictionary, and reforms the data into an easily processed format for multiindex dataframes. Note that if you are using python 3.5+, you will need to use `.items()` rather than `.iteritems()` as shown in the linked answer:

```
>>>>import pandas as pd
>>>>reform = {(firstKey, secondKey, thirdKey): values for firstKey, middleDict in md.items() for secondKey, innerdict in middleDict.items() for thirdKey, values in innerdict.items()}
>>>>df = pd.DataFrame(reform)
```

To change the data type of col1 and col to `int` and `float`, you can then use [pandas.DataFrame.rename()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) and specify any values you want:

```
df.rename({'col1':1, 'col2':2.5}, axis=1, level=2, inplace=True)
```

Also, if you'd rather have the levels on the index rather than the columns, you can also use [pandas.DataFrame.T](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html)

If you wanted to reconstruct your dictionary from this MultiIndex, you could do something like this:

```
>>>>md2={}
>>>>for i in df.columns:
        if i[0] not in md2.keys():
            md2[i[0]]={}
        if i[1] not in md2[i[0]].keys():
            md2[i[0]][i[1]]={}
    md2[i[0]][i[1]][i[2]]=tuple(df[i[0]][i[1]][i[2]].values)
```

Comment: How can I reconstruct my original dictionary from the dataframe?

Comment: @redhotsnow I added a  reconstruction technique to my answer.