# Pandas Dataframe from Python nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nested

I'm trying to create a Pandas dataframe from a python nested dictionary that looks like this:

```
dictionary = {'user1' : {'a': np.array([1,2,3,4]),
                         'b': np.array([6,7,8,9])},

              'user2' : {'a': np.array([2,3,4,5]),
                         'b': np.array([7,8,9,1])}}
```

I'd like the data frame to look like this:

```
      a_w a_x a_y a_z b_w b_x b_y b_z
user1  1   2   3   4   6   7   8   9
user2  2   3   4   5   7   8   9   1
```

EDIT: (where w,x,y,z are markers that tell what the value in the array represent)

I've tried to modify the solution in these question:
[Nested dictionary to multiindex dataframe where dictionary keys are column labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988131/nested-dictionary-to-multiindex-dataframe-where-dictionary-keys-are-column-label/24988227#24988227)

[Construct pandas DataFrame from items in nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575090/construct-pandas-dataframe-from-items-in-nested-dictionary/54300940#54300940)

but cannot get the correct form.

Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: not sure why you would like to have dataframe with duplicated headers...

Comment: See updated reply.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use numpy arrays? Is it allowed to use plain lists instead to answer your question?

Comment: @amanb Yes, the data are large 3d numpy arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the entire thing with a dictionary comprehension, and use `enumerate` to track the index of each element, giving you some semblance of ordering.

```
d = {
  k: {f'{ik}_{idx}': el for ik, iv in v.items() for idx, el in enumerate(iv)}
  for k, v in dictionary.items()
}

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
```

```
       a_0  a_1  a_2  a_3  b_0  b_1  b_2  b_3
user1    1    2    3    4    6    7    8    9
user2    2    3    4    5    7    8    9    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Having duplicated column names is rarely a good idea.. but here you go,

**Update 2**

```
result = pd.concat({key:pd.DataFrame(val,index=['w','x','y','z']) for key,val in dictionary.items()})
           .unstack(-1)
```

You know what, I'm gonna leave the multiindex in the column rather than having _ concatenation. It's often more flexible to leave it this way.

**Update 1**

```
result = (pd.concat({key:pd.DataFrame(val) for key,val in dictionary.items()})
            .unstack(-1).droplevel(1,axis=1)
```

**Original**

```
result = (pd.concat({key:pd.DataFrame(val) for key,val in dictionary.items()})
            .unstack(-1).T
            .reset_index(level=1,drop=True).T)

result
        a   a   a   a   b   b   b   b
user1   1   2   3   4   6   7   8   9
user2   2   3   4   5   7   8   9   1
```

Comment: Nice! Btw. you can avoid the transpose operations (which could be expencsive and can spoil your column types). You can do that by using `result.columns.droplevel(1)` instead of `reset_index`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for the answer. Indeed, you're right about the column names. I made a typo and the column names should be indexed by one of 4 letters: a_w, a_x, a_y, a_z, b_w, b_x, b_y, b_z. I've updated the question. Is it an easy modification of your answer? Thanks again.

Comment: @jottbe haha correct!  I totally forgot that! Actually, since 24, you could apply droplevel on dataframe and control axis. See modified answer.