# How to make multiindex dataframe from a nested dictionary keys and lists of values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have checked the advicse here: [Nested dictionary to multiindex dataframe where dictionary keys are column labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988131/nested-dictionary-to-multiindex-dataframe-where-dictionary-keys-are-column-label)
However, I couldn't get it to work in my problem.
I would like to change a dictionary into multiindexed dataframe, where `'a','b','c'` are names of multiindexes, their values `12,0.8,1.8,bla1,bla2,bla3,bla4` are multiindexes and values from lists are assign to the multiindexes as in the picture of table below.

My dictionary:

```
dictionary ={
            "{'a': 12.0, 'b': 0.8, 'c': ' bla1'}": [200, 0.0, '0.0'],
            "{'a': 12.0, 'b': 0.8, 'c': ' bla2'}": [37, 44, '0.6'],
            "{'a': 12.0, 'b': 1.8, 'c': ' bla3'}": [100, 2.0, '1.0'],
            "{'a': 12.0, 'b': 1.8, 'c': ' bla4'}": [400, 3.0, '1.0']
            }
```

The result DataFrame I would like to get:

[image]

The code which don't make multiindexes and set every values under each other in next row:

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary, orient="index").stack().to_frame()
df_b = pd.DataFrame(df_a[0].values.tolist(), index=df_a.index)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert each string into a dictionary and build the index from there:

```
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

dictionary ={
            "{'a': 12.0, 'b': 0.8, 'c': ' bla1'}": [200, 0.0, '0.0'],
            "{'a': 12.0, 'b': 0.8, 'c': ' bla2'}": [37, 44, '0.6'],
            "{'a': 12.0, 'b': 1.8, 'c': ' bla3'}": [100, 2.0, '1.0'],
            "{'a': 12.0, 'b': 1.8, 'c': ' bla4'}": [400, 3.0, '1.0']
            }


keys, data = zip(*dictionary.items())
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(pd.DataFrame([literal_eval(i) for i in keys]))
res = pd.DataFrame(data=list(data), index=index)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
                  0     1    2
a    b   c                    
12.0 0.8  bla1  200   0.0  0.0
          bla2   37  44.0  0.6
     1.8  bla3  100   2.0  1.0
          bla4  400   3.0  1.0
```