# Accessing dictionaries when having dictionary dataframe values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

### The problem

I am facing a problem as I am managing a dataset each of which entry has associated a dictionary in the form of

```
dictionary = {
    'Step_1': {
        'Q':'123', 
        'W':'456', 
        'E':'789'
    },
    'Step_2': {
        'Q':'753', 
        'W':'159', 
        'E':'888'
    }
}
```

please note that the dicts have a variable number of `Step`s
So I am organising the data into a pandas df like:

```
                                        dicts
0    {'Step_1': {'Q': '123', 'W': '456', ...
1    {'Step_1': {'Q': '123', 'W': '456', ...
2    {'Step_1': {'Q': '123', 'W': '456', ...
```

and would like now to do some row-wise operations, like getting each `dict['Step_1']['Q']` value.

I know that it's generally suggested to not work with dicts as df values, so I'd like to use a good, pythonic (read: fast) solution.

How would you proceed to get each `dict['Step_1']['Q']` row-wise?

### What I tried

A simple solution that came to my mind was:
`df[dicts]['Step_1']['Q']`, but it doesn't seem to work. (Why? Might it be because this way pandas doesn't "unpack" the row values, hence cannot access the dicts?)

A more complex solution that I found to work is to use a function to access the data, as follows:

```
def access(x): 
    return (x["Step_1"]["V"])

df['new_col'] = df['dicts'].apply(lambda x: access(x))
```

but I don't quite like this solution. As far as I know, using the apply method is not the optimal way to tackle the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should reshape your dataset. Check this out:

```
# Let's say we have this
dictionary = {
    "Step_1": {"Q":"123", "W":"456", "E":"789"},
    "Step_2": {"Q":"753", "W":"159", "E":"888"},
}
dicts = [dictionary, dictionary] # This would be your dataset
```

Do this:

```
better = []
for i, d in enumerate(dicts):  # d is a dictionary
    # Iterate over the keys and values of the dictionary
    for k, v in d.items():
        # Get the step from the key
        step = k.split("_")[1]
        # Add this step to the new list
        better.append({"id": i, "step": step, **v})
```

This is what `better` is now:

```
[{'id': 0, 'step': '1', 'W': '456', 'Q': '123', 'E': '789'},
 {'id': 0, 'step': '2', 'W': '159', 'E': '888', 'Q': '753'},
 {'id': 1, 'step': '1', 'W': '456', 'Q': '123', 'E': '789'},
 {'id': 1, 'step': '2', 'W': '159', 'E': '888', 'Q': '753'}]
```

Now you can re-build your DataFrame and perform all kind of row-wise operations:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(better)

    id  step W    Q    E
0   0   1    456  123  789
1   0   2    159  753  888
2   1   1    456  123  789
3   1   2    159  753  888
```

For example, get all of the "Step 1 W" values:

```
df[df.step == "1"].W
# Output:
0    456
2    456
Name: W, dtype: object
```

Note: it's probably a good idea to turn the columns to `int`s, right now they are stored as `str`s

Comment: Ok this looks like exactly what I was looking for! Would you mind updating your comment based on the edit I made to the dictionary in the post? I realised I reported it wrongly at the beginning

Comment: @AntonioCarnevali yep, I edited my answer, you can just remove a couple lines of code

Answer (score 1):

One idea that comes to my mind is to use multi-indexing to unpack the dictionaries that are saved in the dataframe right now.
Say there are two dictionaries:

```
dictionary1 = {
    'Step_1': {
        'Q' :123, 
        'W':456, 
        'E':789
    },
    'Step_2': {
        'Q':753, 
        'W':159, 
        'E':888
    }
}

dictionary2 = {
    'Step_1': {
        'Q' :789, 
        'W':456, 
        'E':123
    },
    'Step_2': {
        'Q':357, 
        'W':951, 
        'E':888
    }
}
```

Then you could create a dataframe from the dictionaries:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([dictionary1, dictionary2])
```

Then, inspired by this thread [Nested dictionary to multiindex dataframe where dictionary keys are column labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988131/nested-dictionary-to-multiindex-dataframe-where-dictionary-keys-are-column-label), you could create the multiindex to unpack the nested dictionaries:

```
multituple = {(outerKey, innerKey): values for outerKey, innerDict in df.iteritems() for innerKey, values in innerDict.iteritems()}
```

This results in Q, W, and E being an index and not a column, but if you have a varying number of steps per dictionary, this might actually be useful since you would not face the issue with varying column lengths.

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(multituple)
    Step_1  Step_2
    0   1   0   1
Q   123 789 753 357
W   456 456 159 951
E   789 123 888 888
```

Hope this gives an idea for you to explore.