# Nested dictionary to multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I'm trying to convert a nested dictionary to multiindex dataframe where dictionary keys are columns labels.

`my_dict = {"season":"summer", "threshold":70, "analysis" : {"max_temp":50, "min_temp":20}}`

I followed the code which is linked to this question [Nested dictionary to multiindex dataframe where dictionary keys are column labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988131/nested-dictionary-to-multiindex-dataframe-where-dictionary-keys-are-column-label)  but I've got an error  **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'**

The following code:

`reform = {(outerKey, innerKey): values for outerKey, innerDict in my_dict.items() for innerKey, values in innerDict.items()}`

Could anyone help me to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, try:

```
my_dict = {"season":"summer", "threshold":70, "analysis" : {"max_temp":50, "min_temp":20}}

df_in = pd.json_normalize(my_dict)

df_in.columns = df_in.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)

df_in
```

Output:

```
   season threshold analysis         
      NaN       NaN max_temp min_temp
0  summer        70       50       20
```